# jQuery parsing xml with some html code. Please help

Tags: jquery, html, xml

I'm not able to get **html** from a very simple XML file as below. In this case I just get a text string as "mots <i>français</i>" and not a html formatted text as "mots *français*" :

```
<content>
  <text id="n1">
    <fr><![CDATA[mots <i>français</i>]]></fr>
    <en><![CDATA[<i>english</i> words]]></en>
  </text>
... and so on
</content>
```

Such xml file using this jQuery script to get strings from XML. Then for every element where I want a different language content, I add a value to a *data-* attribute (i.e. <p data-langtag=n1> ... </p> ).

```
$.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: defaults.file,
 dataType: "xml",
 success: function(xml) {
    $(xml).find('text').each(function() {
    var textId = $(this).attr("id");
    var text = $(this).find(defaults.lang).text();
    aTexts[textId] = text;
    });

    $.each($("*"), function(i, item){
    //alert($(item).attr("data-langtag"));
    if($(item).attr("data-langtag") != null)
    $(item).fadeOut(150).fadeIn(150).text(aTexts[$(item).attr("data-langtag")]);
    });
 }
});
```

It works fine having two clickable elements in the page where to choose english or french.
But it works just using simple text in XML.
I even tried this helper ... https://github.com/kamranayub/jQuery-XML-Helper but no way, it doesn't work here.

Have you any idea about to solve this ?
Tx a lot

Comment: Use `.html()` instead of `.text()` to output your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without actually trying this out, I suspect your problem is that you're using jQuery's `text()` method to set HTML, so it's escaping the angle brackets.  Try:

```
$(item).fadeOut(150).fadeIn(150).html(stuff)
```

Answer (score 0):

wild guess - first & last element in CDATA must be HTML tags:

```
<fr><![CDATA[<span>mots <i>français</i></span>]]></fr>
<en><![CDATA[<span><i>english</i> words</span>]]></en>
```